# Vue.js error 8:3 error Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'new'

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an error in vuex store

error:   8:3  error  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'new'.

```js
// Vuex store
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);


export const store = {
  new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      count: 0,
    },
    getters: {
      increment: (state) => {
        state.count += 1;
      },
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Remove the curlies. `store = new …`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, remove brackets and use syntax mentioned [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

```js
// Vuex store
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);


export const store =
  new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      count: 0,
    },
    getters: {
      increment: (state) => {
        state.count += 1;
      },
    },
  });
```